# Error in connecting to MySql Host

Tags: mysql, connection

Can anyone tell me on how this error arise?

'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

Comment: Need more information. How did you try to connect?

Comment: What're you doing when you get this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742725/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a network problem, more than anything. Also are you sure your allowed to connect to the host in question?

Answer (score 0):

This error arise when you have a bad configuration and/or your host does not respond.